# get UUID, Major, Minor from Estimote Connection

Tags: android, estimote, beacon

I've been unable to find in the documentation of Estimote how to get the UUID, Major or Minor once I established a connection with the beacon.

```
connectionProvider.connectToService(new DeviceConnectionProvider.ConnectionProviderCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectedToService() {
                connection = connectionProvider.getConnection(configurableDevice);
                connection.connect(new DeviceConnectionCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected() {
                    String UUID=connection.settings.beacon.proximityUUID().toString();
}}}
```

This code returns a DeviceSetting but I cannot find where the UUID variable is.
Has anyone been able to figure this out? I need to check the UUID, Major and Minor to see if the Estimote Location Beacon is already registered in my server.

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Yes! It worked like a charm. I just forgot to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`proximityUUID()` returns a `DeviceSetting<UUID>`, so you will have to ask for the value using `get`. Try the following (not tested):

```java
// ds is a DeviceSetting<UUID> instance
ds.get(new SettingCallback<UUID>() {
    @Override
    void onSuccess(UUID value) {
        // There it is    
    }
    @Override
    void onFailure(DeviceConnectionException e) {
    }
})
```